# Highlight rows in a UWP Telerik RadDataGrid depending on values of a certain column

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik

My datagrid is defined as such in xaml

```
<tg:RadDataGrid x:Name="PartDataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="PartNo" Header="Part"/>
        <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Version" Header="Version"/>
        <tg:DataGridDateColumn PropertyName="UpdateDate" Header="Date" CellContentFormat="{}{0: dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
        <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Creator" Header="Creator"/>
    </tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</tg:RadDataGrid>
```

I want something that loop go through all the items and highlight either the cell or the row if the version is a certain value. Is this possible?